# How to disable WSGI debugging (Web application could not be started)?

Tags: python, django, linux

If there is an error in my code, the debugging happens in the browser and the user sees it.

How do I disable the debugging?

I wanted the debugging not to work in the browser
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs7cJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

add **settings.py**

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
}
```